# How to share data structures with Polymer on both client and server

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

**Problem:**
I have a dart file defining some data structures, which I need to use both for the client and for the server. I'd like to make these data structures observable with Polymer. However, the server cannot include the file because of Polymer, because Polymer includes `dart:html`.

**Context:**
I am working on a client/server (REST-full) application, where I want the server to provide the data structures defined available as resources. The client should display these resources, and have the possibility to send the modifications to the server. For that, Polymer is invaluable.

The reason I want to have this library available for the server is that I want the server to be able to validate the resources to be stored.

**Possible solutions:**

I don't yet know the internals of Polymer enough, but if my data structures could inherit from `Map`, I could use `toObservable` in the client side code to make the data structure observable, but instead of accessing by dot notation, I'd have to access members by keys instead, making it rather fragile.

I was wondering if I could use `mirrors.dart` to add the `observable` annotation on the client.

Of course, managing duplicate code, is really not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `observe` package.

With `ChangeNotifier` you initiate the change notification yourself by calling `notifyPropertyChange` when a value changes. The changes get delivered synchronously.

`Observable` needs `dirtyCheck()` to be called to deliver changes.

Polymer calls `Observable.dirtyCheck()` repeatedly to get the changes automatically.

**an example for each**

```dart
import 'package:observe/observe.dart';

class Notifiable extends Object with ChangeNotifier {
  String _input = '';

  @reflectable
  get input => _input;

  @reflectable
  set input(val) {
    _input = notifyPropertyChange(#input, _input, val + " new");
  }

  Notifiable() {
    this.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> record) => record.forEach(print));
  }
}

class MyObservable extends Observable {
  @observable
  String counter = '';

  MyObservable() {
    this.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> record) => record.forEach(print));
  }
}

void main() {
  var x = new MyObservable();
  x.counter = "hallo";
  Observable.dirtyCheck();

  Notifiable notifiable = new Notifiable();
  notifiable.input = 'xxx';
  notifiable.input = 'yyy';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't gotten accustomed to automatic imports yet.

Comment: Note: The `this.changes.listen ...` part is only necessary if you want to be notified about changes yourself. Polymer doesn't need it - just to be sure ;-).

Comment: Hello tusj, you might want to look at the libarary at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/model_map.